# Why does flutter need git in windows?

Tags: git, dart, flutter

I saw that Flutter requires "git" as a system requirement when installing in Windows. I tried searching for it but they haven't mentioned the reason on why it's required.

Does Flutter in any way make use of version control during its execution, if so, is it responsible for hot reload and how? If not, why does it need Git?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Git is not related to hot-reload.

Currently Git is used to switch channels (`beta`, `dev`, `master`)
and only download changes when installing updates

See also https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading