# Weird behavior of flutter and dart commands in PowerShell and CMD

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm relatively new to Flutter but I already have developed and finished some Apps in Flutter.
Recently I noticed a weird behavior of commands with the keywords "dart" or "flutter" in it.

Here is an example:
I was trying to migrate an existing project to the new dart null-safety and typed the command `dart migrate` into my Visual-Studio-Code Terminal.
I was expecting an output like `Migrating C:\....` as a response but instead got these three lines:

```
The command "git" is either misspelled or could not be found.
Building flutter tool... 
Running pub upgrade...
```

and then the expected output:

```
Migrating C:\<project path>...
```

and so on.

So basically the commands work as they would normally do but I get these three lines before the output everytime. And it's not only with this command. Also basic commands like `dart help` or `flutter doctor` will get these three lines.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I uninstalled Flutter and also removed it from the PATH and then reinstalled it freshly but it's still the same. I also searched the web but didn't found anyone who has the same problem.

Any help and explanation would be great. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Flutter [system requirements](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#system-requirements) on Windows and [git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does flutter need git in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53477198/why-does-flutter-need-git-in-windows)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I installed git but then the first line "The command "git" is either misspelled or could not be found." isn't showing but the other two lines are still showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know where the problem is. I ran the commands directly when I opened PowerShell. But the directory was something like `C:\Windows\` and then it won't work.
After I did `cd C:\Users\User` all commands will work as expected.

I was just thinking that it doesn't matter from **where** I run `dart`and `flutter`commands obviously you have to be in your user directory that they will work properly.